# Logstash Grok filter for uwsgi logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm a new user to ELK stack. I'm using UWSGI as my server. I need to parse my uwsgi logs using Grok and then analyze them.

Here is the format of my logs:-

```
[pid: 7731|app: 0|req: 357299/357299] ClientIP () {26 vars in 511 bytes} [Sun Mar  1 07:47:32 2015] GET /?file_name=123&start=0&end=30&device_id=abcd&verif_id=xyzsghg => generated 28 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

I used [this link](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/discover?#) to generate my filter, but it didn't parse much of the information.

The filter generated by the above link is

```
%{SYSLOG5424SD} %{IP} () {26 vars in 511 bytes} %{SYSLOG5424SD} GET %{URIPATHPARAM} => generated 28 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP%{URIPATHPARAM} 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Here is my logstash-conf file.

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424SD} %{IP} () {26 vars in 511 bytes} %{SYSLOG5424SD} GET %{URIPATHPARAM} => generated 28 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP%{URIPATHPARAM} 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Upon running logstash with this conf file, I get an error message saying:-

```
{
       "message" => "[pid: 7731|app: 0|req: 357299/357299] ClientIP () {26 vars in 511 bytes} [Sun Mar  1 07:47:32 2015] GET /?file_name=123&start=0&end=30&device_id=abcd&verif_id=xyzsghg => generated 28 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-03-01T07:57:02.291Z",
          "host" => "cube26-Inspiron-3542",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

The date has been properly formatted. How do I extract other information from my logs, such as my `query parameters(filename, start,end, deviceid etc)` and `ClientIP` , `Response code` etc.

Also, is there any built-in UWSGI log parser which can be used, such as the one built for apache and syslog?

**EDIT**

I wrote this on my own, but it throws the same error:

```
%{SYSLOG5424SD} %{IP:client_ip} () {%{NUMBER:vars} vars in %{NUMBER:bytes} bytes} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} => generated %{NUMBER:generated_bytes} bytes in {NUMBER:secs} msecs (HTTP/1.0 %{NUMBER:response_code}) %{NUMBER:headers} headers in %{NUMBER:header_bytes} (1 switches on core 0)
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm finally able to crack it myself. The GROK filter for the above log will be:

```
\[pid: %{NUMBER:pid}\|app: %{NUMBER:app}\|req: %{NUMBER:req_num1}/%{NUMBER:req_num2}\] %{IP:client_ip} \(\) \{%{NUMBER:vars} vars in %{NUMBER:bytes} bytes\} %{SYSLOG5424SD} %{WORD:method} /\?file_name\=%{NUMBER:file_name}\&start\=%{NUMBER:start}\&end\=%{NUMBER:end} \=\> generated %{NUMBER:generated_bytes} bytes in %{NUMBER:secs} msecs \(HTTP/1.0 %{NUMBER:response_code}\) %{NUMBER:headers} headers in %{NUMBER:header_bytes}
```

But my questions still remain:

1. is there any default uwsgi log filter in grop??**
2. I've been applying different matches for different query parameters. Is there anything in grok that fetches the different query parameters by itself??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution for extracting the query parameters:-

Here is my final configuration:-

For log line

```
[pid: 7731|app: 0|req: 426435/426435] clientIP () {28 vars in 594 bytes} [Mon Mar  2 06:43:08 2015] GET /?file_name=wqvqwv&start=0&end=30&device_id=asdvqw&verif_id=qwevqwr&lang=English&country=in => generated 11018 bytes in 25 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 2 headers in 82 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

the configuration is

```
input { stdin { } }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[pid: %{NUMBER}\|app: %{NUMBER}\|req: %{NUMBER}/%{NUMBER}\] %{IP} \(\) \{%{NUMBER} vars in %{NUMBER} bytes\} %{SYSLOG5424SD:DATE} %{WORD} %{URIPATHPARAM} \=\> generated %{NUMBER} bytes in %{NUMBER} msecs \(HTTP/1.0 %{NUMBER}\) %{NUMBER} headers in %{NUMBER}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
  kv {
    field_split => "&? "
    include_keys => [ "file_name", "device_id", "lang", "country"]
  }
}


output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found your solution did't support HTTP/1.1. I fixed it and also add variables name. [Ref](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2015-March/007949.html)

Here's my grok config:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "\[pid: %{NUMBER:pid}\|app: %{NUMBER:id}\|req: %{NUMBER:currentReq}/%{NUMBER:totalReq}\] %{IP:remoteAddr} \(%{WORD:remoteUser}?\) \{%{NUMBER:CGIVar} vars in %{NUMBER:CGISize} bytes\} %{SYSLOG5424SD:timestamp} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:uri} \=\> generated %{NUMBER:resSize} bytes in %{NUMBER:resTime} msecs \(HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpVer} %{NUMBER:status}\) %{NUMBER:headers} headers in %{NUMBER:headersSize} bytes %{GREEDYDATA:coreInfo}" }
}
date {
  match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
```